# Linking error when including <pcl/io/png_io.h> in more than one file

Tags: point-cloud-library

I wanted to use `pcl::io::savePNGFile` in two source-files in my code.

As soon as I include the required include in second source-file

```
# include <pcl/io/png_io.h>
```

the project doesn't compile.

The error message is:

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/png_io.h:86: multiple definition of `pcl::io::saveRgbPNGFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char const*, int, int)'
```

I'm going to wrap the function in a class in order to include it only once in project. But I think it is not the best way. Am I doing something in a wrong way? Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

EDIT

Finally I've implemented a Q&D solution and wrapped the function (only for normal clouds)

cloudsaver.h

```
#ifndef CLOUDSAVER_H
#define CLOUDSAVER_H        

#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <string>

class CloudSaver
{

public:
    CloudSaver();

    void saveCloudToPNG(const std::string & fileName, const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>& cl );
};

#endif // CLOUDSAVER_H
```

cloudsaver.cpp

```
#include "cloudsaver.h"

# include <pcl/io/png_io.h>

CloudSaver::CloudSaver()
{

}

void CloudSaver::saveCloudToPNG(const std::string & fileName, const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>& cl )
{
    pcl::io::savePNGFile<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>(fileName, cl );
}
```

But I'm still curious, how to do it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, There are some issues related to png_io.h.

I have change the definition of PCL_DEPRECATED in png_io.h file with this definition,and every thing becomes OK.

```
template <typename T>
PCL_DEPRECATED (void savePNGFile (const std::string& file_name, const pcl::PointCloud<T>&     cloud),
"pcl::io::savePNGFile<typename T> (file_name, cloud) is deprecated, please use a new generic "
"function pcl::io::savePNGFile (file_name, cloud, field_name) with \"rgb\" as the field name."
);
```

look at this link [https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/300]

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know, what is the replacement for savePNG if this function is deprecated? I need to save a view on the cloud from defined perspective as an image.

Comment: I have found a new SavePNG function which is discussed here: [https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/204] and the code is also here, https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/commit/9493da243331dd32f928f9c0a2e37101fe25bb29      Thanks to PCL developers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the static version of PCL.

To solve this issue you need to declare those methods as **inline**.

For example, for PCL 1.7.1, you need to edit this file:
pcl-pcl-1.7.1/io/include/pcl/io/png_io.h

And on these lines, add the keyword inline:

```
85: inline saveRgbPNGFile(...
96: inline savePNGFile(...
107: inline savePNGFile(...
119: inline savePNGFile(...
173: inline savePNGFile(...
```

Now rebuild the library, and you should be able to compile without any issues.